# Basic question on CRO usage

Tags: signal

I have to measure signals using oscilloscope on all the four lines in following circuit. J1, and j5 are headers given by the manufacturer on the board (MACHX02 1200-ZE). I connected ground lead of the probe to the ground on the board and other lead on of the lines one by one.

My friend says that you should not look at the waveforms this way, instead you must isolate/disconnect two chips, FT2232H and MachX02, and then measure the signals.

Is it really required to do so?

[image]

Comment: The only reason you would want to break the connection between the two devices would be if you need to determine which IC is driving which data-line. If you know the directionality of each connection, you do not need to disconnect the devices.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what you are trying to do, but I would normally want to look at the circuit as it is normally used.  If the observed signals are low level or distorted, or otherwise not what I expect, then I might consider more invasive techniques.

Comment: Can you tell me what are more invasive techniques you might employ?

Comment: @gpuguy - cutting connections, measuring resistance (with power off!!) - depends on problems found.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine what your friend is talking about.  An Oscilloscope is made to observe voltage waveforms ,for the most part, without disturbing/effecting them.  What he seems to be suggesting is very disruptive.

If anything you will examining these signals in relationship to each other, so you will be connecting multiple channels of the O'scope at the same time.